# Angular Material DateTimePicker not rendering the Calender

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, datetimepicker

I am using [DateTimePicker](https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.0/demo/datepicker), I followed the demo and included in my Project but it is not rendering the calendar to choose the date and also it's lagging, For the record, I double checked the Includes and no console errors till now.

Code:
    `<md-datepicker  ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Departs on"></md-datepicker>`

Output:

[image: Here is the Calendar Itself]

Comment: do you see any errors in console?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Nope, I already Mentioned that in Question.

Comment: shall i show a working one or can you create a plunker for your issue?

Comment: @Sajeetharan I am facing the issue in my project, I am doing all things right I am not getting what the issue is I have used this picker in past.

Comment: @Sajeetharan Any way out to see what's the actual problem is? any troubleshooting procedure  in angular?